# YII HTML rendering

Tags: backbone.js, mvvm, knockout.js, yii, ember.js

I use YII widgets for making my views and rely on CGridView, CLiStData, CHtml classes.. 
I often see comparison online between client side MV* frameworks like Ember, backbone .. and then I use jquery in YII for adding all interactivity. But, the views are being made from widgets.

So, My question is YII a server side HTML rendering framework ?

Comment: Yes, you might say that HTML rendering is purpose of Yii...

Comment: There is a YII extension to help create a rest api also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Really, what's the question about?

If you ask if Yii can cooperate with some MVVM (Model-View-View-Model) library, like knockout or backbone then answer is yes and no. As generally Yii generates widgets as static HMTL, somewhat enchanced with jQuery. For trully MVVM widgets, you have to make them by your own. Most common case is `CActiveForm`, to make form bindable to view model.

Personally I use knockoutjs wih yii and made quick and dirty patched version of `CActiveFrom` (strictly Im using `TbActiveForm` from `YiiBooster`, but thats not important here) to add bindings and it works fine.

Isn't it similar question to [Yii and Knockout Together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11449417/yii-and-knockout-together)

Comment: I am working on a YII website with so many jquery event bindings in background that I started checking in some auto - binding options. Then, I had this doubt why YII has its most of View rendering done in server side ?

Comment: Yii was designed when there was no such frameworks. It is very good from server side operations. but from client side there are plenty of options, from which Yii use technique from time whet it was made. But if you know whats up with modern client side frameworks its up to you to make inteface usefull for end clients